# td is not taking height according to inside iframe & its elements height in Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, iframe, html-table

I have a table in which a "td" is not taking its full height according to its child.

I add snapshot of my HTML tags arrangement:

[image: HTML Code]

If you can see "td" is highlight inside this td I have iframe inside it there is a svg element with its properties and its size of 400*300 px.

So, If I run these HTML on chrome it looks like below:

[image]

and if I run this on Firefox 26.0 then it looks like:

[image]

Now, I want Firefox same result on every browser. How can I achieve this task?